# retrieve real-time data from JBloomberg API

Tags: java, real-time-data, jbloomberg

I want to retrieve the time and the real-time last Price as double instead of having an output like

```
DataChangeEvent{ESA Index,ASK_SIZE: 204==>192}
```

from the code below

```
DataChangeListener lst = new DataChangeListener() {
 @Override
 public void dataChanged(DataChangeEvent e) {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
};


SubscriptionBuilder builder = new SubscriptionBuilder()
     .addSecurity("ESA Index")
     .addField(RealtimeField.LAST_PRICE)
     .addField(RealtimeField.ASK)
     .addField(RealtimeField.ASK_SIZE)
     .addListener(lst);
session.subscribe(builder);


Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw your question so it's probably a little late - but here it is anyway. [DataChangeEvent](http://assylias.github.io/jBloomberg/apidocs/index.html) contains the ticker, the field, the new and old price:

```
DataChangeListener lst = new DataChangeListener() {
     @Override public void dataChanged(DataChangeEvent e) {
         String ticker = e.getSource();
         String field = e.getDataName();
         double oldValue = e.getOldValue().asDouble();
         double newValue = e.getNewValue().asDouble();
     }
};
```